# How to assign custom keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, customization, system-settings

I tried doing it by `Keyboard > Custom Shortcuts > +`, where I can enter the Name and Command just fine, but I can't seem to understand how to assign a keyboard shortcut to it. It just says Disabled.

I read the line which says `To edit a shortcut, click the row and hold down the new keys or press Backspace to clear`, but when I click on the row, I just get this:

[image]

Nothing happens if I press any key combination. It closes only after I click Apply, and then also stays at `Disabled`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to click on the word `Disabled` which should then become:

[image]

And all you will need to do then is to press the key combination you want to execute the command you assigned to this keyboard shortcut. So for instance if I then typed (without the `+` or any spacing):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

I would get this and the keyboard shortcut would be assigned:

[image]

Comment: @AnukulSangwan: You're welcome! It's the Ubuntu GNOME Global Dark Theme. :)

Comment: Though I have combined that with the Numix theme.